# Difference between "process virtual machine" with "system virtual machine"

Tags: virtual-machine

What's the difference between process virtual machine with system virtual machine?

My guess is that process VM is not providing a kind of an operating system for the whole application for that OS, rather providing an environment for some specific application.
And system VM is providing an environment for an OS to be installed just like VirtualBox.
Am I getting it correct?

Another question is the difference between the two different implementation of system VM: hosted vs. stand-alone.

I'm a beginner studying OS, so easy and understandable answer would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: A related link: http://opensourceforu.com/2011/06/virtual-machines-for-abstraction-dalvik-vm/

Answer (score 31):

A **Process virtual machine**, sometimes called an application virtual machine, runs as a normal application inside a host OS and supports a single process. It is created when that process is started and destroyed when it exits. Its purpose is to provide a platform-independent programming environment that abstracts away details of the underlying hardware or operating system, and allows a program to execute in the same way on any platform.

A **System virtual machine** provides a complete system platform which supports the execution of a complete operating system (OS),Just like you said *VirtualBox* is one example.

A **Host virtual machine** is the server component of a virtual machine , which provides computing resources in the underlying hardware to support guest virtual machine (guest VM).

Comment: Hmm... This text is just copy-paste from Wikipedia. I don't blame you, but _is_ Wine process virtual machine actually? I believe JVM is, but I'm not sure about Wine.

Comment: is process virtual machine related to emulation concept or am i going in the wrong direction?

Answer (score 2):

The following is from http://airccse.org/journal/jcsit/5113ijcsit11.pdf : 
System Virtual Machines
A System Virtual Machine gives a complete virtual hardware platform with support for execution
of a complete operating system (OS).
The advantage of using System VM are:

- Multiple Operating System environments can run in parallel on the same piece of
  hardware in strong isolation from each other.
- The VM can provide an instruction set architecture (ISA) that is slightly different from
  that of the real machine

The main draw backs are:

- Since the VM indirectly accesses the same hardware the efficiency is compromised.
- Multiply VMs running in parallel on the same physical machine may result in varied
  performance depending on the workload imposed on the system. Implementing proper
  isolation techniques may address this drawback.